# UART Overrun Error handling when transmitting data onto a terminal (lpc2138)

Tags: c, uart, lpc

I am making a driver code for lpc2138. Currently I need to read the voltage on a potentiometer with the ADC and with the use of timer, print it onto a terminal in regular intervals. There are also other components but they are not of interest for this issue.

Now I'm having troubles sending it to UART to display it on the terminal. I used the simple (actually probably the most common) function for sending data to UART buffer:

```
void uart0_write(char reg_data)/*send one byte*/
{
        while(!(U0LSR & THRE)); /*wait for THRE in LSR 5th bit to be empty*/
            U0THR = (int) reg_data; /*write data into THR(transmit buffer, right?*/
}

void uart0_write_str(char *str)/*send a string*/
{
    /*
    Should something come here?
    */

    while(*str != 0x00) /*while not end of string*/
    {
        uart0_write(*str); /*send one char*/
        str++; /*move +1 char in the array*/
    }
}
```

And here is the U0 init code:

```
void uart0_init(void)
{
    PINSEL0 = 0x05; /*set pin P0.0 to TXD0 and P0.1 RxD0 (TXD0 - 01; RxD0 - 01; 0101 = 0x05)*/
    U0LCR = 0x83; /*set length for 8-bit word, set the stop bit, enable DLAB*/
    //U0IER = (1<<0) | (1<<1);/*Enable THRE interrupts; Do I need this ?*/
    U0FCR = 0xC7;*/ /*enable FIFO; reset Tx FIFO; set interrupt after 14 characters*/

    /*Baud rate configured to 9600 Baud*/
    U0DLL = 0x9D;
    U0DLM = 0x0;

    U0LCR = 0x03; /*disable DLAB*/
}
```

Timer setup:

```
void timer0_setup(void)
{
    T0CTCR = 0x00;/*select timer mode*/
    T0TCR = 0x02; /*reset and halt the timer*/
    T0PR = 25000 - 1; /*prescaler set to granularity with 1ms steps*/
    T0MR0 = 200 - 1; /*set match register to interrupt every 200ms*/
    T0MCR = 0x03; /*generate interrupt on each 3rd pulse of PCLK and reset the timer*/
}
```

Timer handler:

```
int t0flag; /*global int flag for starting the ADC conversion; used later in main*/

void timer0_handler(void)
{
    t0flag = 0;

    T0IR = (1<<0); /*reset the timer*/
    VICVectAddr = 0x00; /*reset the VIC address*/
}
```

**The Problem**
When I try to run it in a simulator, an overrun error pops up.

What could be the issue? normally if I'd write in main:

```
char *str = "Hello World";
extern int t0flag = 1;

while(1)
{
    if(t0flag == 0)
    {
        /*do what is necessary*/
        t0flag = 1;
    }
}
```

It should output the string, right? I have been reading the data sheets and all the information available on the web and cannot figure it out. Is my approach incorrect?

I'd be thankful for any hint!

Jacob

Comment: what hardware is this software running on?

Comment: it runs on Proteus, lpc2138 - 32bit ARM7 In the datasheet there is also: UART 16C550. In Proteus there is just a virtual terminal as an option to choose.

Comment: you might want to read: <http://www.keil.com/download/docs/297.asp>  and open the link to `LPC2100 Insider's Guide'  Then look over the code example for the UART

Comment: the uart overrun bit is related to input, so I'm a bit wondering about it becoming set during output

Comment: `(int) reg_data` How does this cast make any sense? Isn't the data register 8 bits? In general you should start using the types from stdint.h instead.

Comment: If you get overrun errors in the receiving end, I'd first of all suspect the baudrate. Measure it with your scope.